# Seleção de linhas por palavra chave VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tenho aqui um documento bem grande e preciso selecionar todas as linhas que tenham a palavra chave "title", usando a ferramenta de busca consigo filtrar todas as linhas, mas não achei nenhum comando para selecionar todas elas de uma vez. Tentei usar o <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>, mas acabo selecionando apenas uma linha em que a palavra chave aparece.

[image: foto do documento]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecione a palavra que você quer usar como base (com o cursor mesmo, sem usar a ferramenta de busca). No seu caso, será "title".

Depois pressione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> para selecionar todas as ocorrências. Depois pressione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> para selecionar as linhas por completo.

Answer (score -1):

A resposta funciona, porem para quem usa a extensão Visual Studio Keymap, pode acontecer um conflito, e esses comandos são para a exclusão de linha e cut, para contornar isso pode ir nos atalhos (ctrl+k ctrl+s) e alterar ou deletar os comandos que são da extensão